# ChromaDB, OpenAI: How to describe user interaction and make it understandable for openAI

Tags: openai-api, chromadb

I have a knowledge base (description of users and companies) stored in a chromadb vector database. Then I have a relational database where I store user interaction in my app (which and how many times profiles he visited, texts he read, videos he played, profiles he commented). I am planning to use OpenAI to make recommendations to a user based on both stored knowledge and his own previous interaction.

**Why I want to do that?**
I want suggest company profiles to user, he may like.

**What I do know how to do?** Knowledge base works perfectly. Texts about user are matched against company descriptions and the most suitable companies are found for user.

**What I don't know how to do?** The question is how to provide that user interaction data to OpenAI in order to OpenAI will understand it, since the data are just relations and numbers. I was thinking about transforming the data into following sentences...

- "I am interested into 'name of article' and visited it 'count' times"
- "I visited profile of company 'name of company' 'count' times and
  interacted with contact form"
- "I visited profile of company 'other
  company name' once and clicked that i don't want to receive
  notifications from this company anymore."

And pack these sentences as an additive context for OpenAI query. But is this correct approach? Can you suggest me a right / optimal solution for this?